# Will Google penalize news website for duplicate content when it links to original stories along with the full text?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

My website is similar to news.google.com.
news.goole.com link's to original source, and shows some of the content from the target page. My website copies the content of the original source and shows  users the copied content with a link to original source.

My question is will Google penalize my website as duplicate content?
For SEO, what way is better: link to original source or show copied content to user?

My website language is Persian (Farsi), ca Google detect duplicate content in Persian language?

Comment: Google will always find duplicate content regardless of the language. It uses semantic scoring for this. Duplicate content must use a canonical tag to refer to the original page to avoid issues with search engines.

Comment: Are you translating articles into Farsi, or copying Farsi text from other sites?

Comment: copy Farsi text from other sites

Comment: my website copy Farsi text from other sites,add reference and link's to original source. this is duplicate content?

Answer (score 1):

Copied content (regardless of language of content) is considered offering nothing of value to your visitors. For this reason, you can expect search engines to not index your website at best. You may also expect manual actions taken against your site in Google Webmaster tools if you have an account with them.

> For SEO, what way is better: link to original source or show copied content to user?

If those were the only choices you have, I'd go with link to the original source. If you want a chance of having your pages indexed, provide some unique content on the page with the link, not a page that shows only one link on the screen. By unique content, I'd aim for at least a couple hundred words that can make the user understand what the page is about.

Comment: Links to original source. my scope is , show the title of news and when click on redirect to original source, no a page that shows only one link on the screen